# Left join if no data, otherwise Inner join

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a view **V** which selects data from a few tables. I also have a table **T** that defines which type of data in **V** a user is allowed to see.

For a user, if there is no data in **T**, that means he's allowed to see everything from my view **V**, but if there is data in **T**, then I need to restrict the result of my view **V**.

So in my mind, I would need to do a `V Left join T` if nothing in **T** or an `V INNER JOIN T` if something in **T**.

But I'm not too sure how to write this query to have the best performances possible (in term of server execution), providing the view **V** could already be a not-so-fast query to execute. should I first select everything from B and store it in some variable or temporary table? Or could everything be done easily with a clever SQL syntax I haven't heard about so far?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Your word problem is intangible and very distracting.

Comment: Sorry I thought keeping it simple by not going into too much detail was a better idea but now I see your point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than focusing on the "inner join/outer join" part of your question, I would suggest doing this in two steps.

First, your application could query table "T" to determine the access privileges of the user.  Then, secondly, use the data in "T" to determine what the user can access in "V".

If you are writing a server application where you control both the database layer and the business layer, then write a procedure to gather all the user's permissions settings first, then do one of two queries - either a privileged query or a nonprivileged query, depending on the contents of T.

If you have to do this all in the data layer, here's how to do it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
    @current_user int
AS

-- Determine user's permission level
DECLARE @permission bit
SELECT @permission = permission FROM T WHERE t.user = @current_user

-- Use the appropriate query for this user
IF @permission IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM V
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM V INNER JOIN T ON T.criteria=V.criteria
END
```

Answer (score 2):

It can only be done with an inner join if you have a 'default' user that has all rows in T. Otherwise you're down to something like this:

```
select V.*
from V,
T
where (v.id = T.Id 
AND T.User = current_user)
OR NOT EXISTS (select 1 from T where T.user=current_user)
```

Comment: +1 as this would work but the other answer looks "easier" to apply in my situation. Many thanks for your help though!